# Edits that expand an answer

Tags: discussion, editing

I was processing the edit review que, and I came across [this suggested edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23081).  I'm not entirely sure what to do in such a situation.  The edit added some valuable information, but I'm hesitant to allow people to insert new things into another person's answer.

In this case it seems worthwhile, as it was valuable information.  Other times though, the information could be incorrect, and may negatively impact the original poster (through no fault of their own).  As a reviewers, our knowledge is not perfect, and we may not catch such errors.

I chose to 'skip' this review. How should such edits be treated in the future? A case by case basis, or a flat restriction on the practice?  Personally, I prefer the later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would reject the edit. This edit should be made as a comment or a separate answer.

I allow edits if it does not change the original poster's intent. In this case as you pointed out the edits added info that the original poster did not say, and should not be held accountable for.